# Redirect back with input not working in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, redirect, input, laravel-5.5, back

I've used redirect back with input many times previously. But in this project I'm unable to do so. This is my **controller** method that handles the form request:

```
public function verifyMobileCode( Request $request)
{
        $userId = Auth::user()->id;
        if( Auth::user()->verification_code == $request['verification_code'])
        {
            User::where('id', $userId)->update(['verified'=>1]);
            return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Account verified.');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors('verification_code' ,'unv' )->withInput($request->all());
        }
}
```

This is my form blade:

```
@extends('layouts.index')

@section('content')

<div class="container" style='padding-top: 150px;'>

    <?php var_dump($errors) ; ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Verify your mobile</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('verifyMobileCode') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('verification_code') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="verification_code" class="col-md-4 control-label">Verification code</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="verification_code" type="text" class="form-control" name="verification_code" value="{!! old('verification_code') !!}" required autofocus maxlength="6" pattern="\d{6}">

                                @if ($errors->has('verification_code'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>Please enter 6 digit number sent to your mobile.</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

My Kernel.php is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\LanguageSwitcher::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'is-admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdminMiddleware::class,
    ];
}
```

I do not find any error or something wrong. Is there anything you see? Is there any **technique to debug this behaviour?** Thaks in advance.

Comment: Whole logic of checking of `Auth::check()` should be in middleware.

Comment: @Kyslik, redirect back is working and the control is passing inside the Auth::check() , so I think it should have worked. Any I tried it. I used middleware instead of Auth::check() and removed from controller still same issue.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that user is logged in already when hitting `verifyMobileCode()` ?

Comment: @Kyslik, you are absolutely correct, user is logged in to get to this route.

Comment: Is the issue related to the `old()` being empty ? What does a `dd()` for your last redirect with input show?

Comment: This one can really work for you

 `return redirect()->back()->withErrors('verification_code' ,'unv')->withInput();` But what is not showing?? Errors or input fields when the request fails. Please let me now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach would be using [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation).

```
php artisan make:request VerifyCodeRequest
```

And body of the request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class VerifyCodeRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'verification_code' => 'required|in:'.$this->user()->verification_code, // since user is already logged in we check if verification_code matches using `in` rule
        ];
    }


    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'in' => 'Your custom error message if we failed',
        ];
    }
}
```

Now you change signature of `verifyMobileCode(...)` to the following `verifyMobileCode(App\Http\Requests\VerifyCodeRequest $request)`.

Now, code executes body of the function **only if** we pass the validation so we need to update user instance and we are done.

```
public function verifyMobileCode(App\Http\Requests\VerifyCodeRequest $request)
{
    $request->user()->verify();
    return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Account verified.');
}
```

Inside User model add `verify()` function

```
public function verify() 
{
    $this->update(['verified' => true]);
}
```

---

If your above approach does not work the there is some issue with your **`app/Http/Kernel.php`**. You have used

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

twice. You must delete one. Probably the first one.

See the stock Laravel's [kernel.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php).

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: Hello Kyslik, today I'm trying all solutions. Wait few hours.

Comment: @Puru I don’t care about bounty or score; if the answer does not work comment; if it works comment as well; so answerer (in this case me) can act on it.

Comment: That's nice of you , I 'm checking all of these before that I have to sort out some other bugs.

Comment: Hello Kyslik, I'm getting this error would you help me sort this out.  Method [validateRequired|in] does not exist.

Comment: @Puru I edited the answer, it should be `string` instead of `array`. **Note**: its possible to send array but every rule has to be each own key.

Comment: I tried this as well but I'm not getting error and old value back.

Comment: @Puru *If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed to the session so they are available for display. If the request was an AJAX request, a HTTP response with a 422 status code will be returned to the user including a JSON representation of the validation errors.* Straight from the Laravel documentation. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Its not ajax request. I must be doing some thing wrong but unable to find out. Ya in case of failed validation it takes me back, but not getting error and old value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171152/discussion-between-kyslik-and-puru).

Comment: @Puru You have \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, two times delete one in 'web' array. That should solve your issue with sessions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `->withInput($request->all());` with `->withInput();`

if you dont want any one of the input use

`->withInput(
    $request->except('input_name')
);`

Answer (score 0):

To debug this without resorting to Xdebug the quick way is to add temporary debug code to the start of the blade file:

```
@php
    dd($errors->toArray(), $errors->has('verification_code'));
@endphp
```

Which will give you the following output:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:1 [
    0 => "verification_code"
  ]
]
false
```

This shows that the logic in the blade file is not being evaluated to *true* which is required to show the error styles and message.

The quick fix is to change the controller to use:

```
->withErrors(['verification_code' => 'unv'])
```

withErrors expects as MessageBag or array, but will cast a string to an array which does not result in the proper key/value pair.

The debug output will now show:

```
array:1 [
  "verification_code" => array:1 [
    0 => "unv"
  ]
]
true
```

The debug code can now be removed and the error should be displayed as you expect.

The proper Laravel way is probably to use $request->validate() or a FormRequest for complex forms. For more information see the Laravel validation documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation).

Answer (score 0):

```php
return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors('verification_code' ,'unv' );
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: `return back()` is a handy new way to redirect back.

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller should look like this:

```
public function verifyMobileCode( Request $request)
{
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    if( Auth::user()->verification_code == $request['verification_code'])
    {
        User::where('id', $userId)->update(['verified'=>1]);
        return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Account verified.');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors('message' ,'Please some errors encountered.' );
    }
}
```

And modify this

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('verification_code') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
```

To this:

```
<div class="form-group>
@include('errors');
```

Also create file called `errors.blade.php` in resources/views and put the following code:

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="card"> //incase bootstrap 4
    <div class="error card-body alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

Hope it works for you. But you dont need to display old inputs since the code will be wrong or something wrong has happened. So its not necessary

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I tried it , did not work.

Answer (score 0):

**In controller**

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors('verification_code' ,'unv')->withInput();
```

**In view**

if you want to retrieve the validated input field value then you need to use laravel `FORM` class for `<form></form>` as well as `<input>` fields

example

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'post','url' => 'Your url','class'=>'form-horizontal']) }}

     {{ Form::text('verification_code','',['class'=>'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

anybody on Laravel 8, this should work

```
return back()->withErrors('your error message is here');
```

If you look at the signature of the `withErrors` function, second param is the key and it is set to `default` unless you want it to be something specific.